# confluent-kafka in AWS Python Lambda. Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to attach confluent_kafka as a layer to a Python3.9 lambda function and am getting this error.

`Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl`

I have other layers on the same function for requests and neo4j which are working fine, but confluent is not.

To install the layer, I have use `pip3 install -t python confluent-kafka`. Python is an empty folder. I then zip the python folder up and deploy the layer. I am using terraform to deploy.

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71908631/aws-lambda-importerror-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-no-module-nam) and ensured there are no sub directories under the parent.
[image]

They layer is attached
[image]

My import line for confluent_kafka:
[image]

How can I resolve this issue and import the package?

Comment: I can see you are using python folder as a target for confluent-kafka package and you mentioned that folder is empty?

Comment: Which python version installed in machine where you are creating layer?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Correct, I created a local folder called python, which is empty to install the package into. My local machine is running python3.10.12

Comment: Ok then can you please first install python 3.9 in your machine and then install the package? Also which os you are using windows, mac or linux?